# Alternative to deepcopy a lit of BitVectors in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-copy

In my project, I am using `deepcopy()` function to create a deep copy a list of `BitVector`s. Unfortunately, its taking a lot of time.

```
a = [<BitVector obj at 0x000...>, <BitVector obj at 0x000...>, <BitVector obj at 0x000...> ...]
```

On changing `a`, I do not want `b` to reflect the changes.

```
b = deepcopy(a)
```

But the above equation is taking a lot of time. What alternative should I use for better performance?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to deep-copy the list? If the list is large it obviously is going to take a lot of time regardless of the method (and, I believe, `deepcopy` is the best you could do here).

Comment: What is "a lot of time"? milliseconds/seconds/minutes/hours? Also did you profile your code and you discovered that most of the time is spent in copying those arrays?

Comment: @Bakuriu Here, "a lot of time" is in reference to the total time taken by an input. If input 'x' takes 10 seconds then ~60% of time is spent in deep copying. Larger inputs take approx 500 seconds and again ~ 300-350 seconds are used for deep copying. I found this by profiling the code. I used cProfile module.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Thank you. Even i think it is the best idea so far! Please let me know if i can use something else.

Comment: Did you consider simply improving your algorithm to avoid copying all those times? We cannot help with that without knowing the whole code...

Answer (score 1):

The `BitVector` implementation is pure python and copying could be optimised substantially. Further, the provided implementation of `BitVector.deep_copy` is substantially slower than `copy.deepcopy`. Here is a an implementation of a deep copy that is ~10 times faster on my machine.

```
def bitvector_copy(bitvector):
    new = BitVector.__new__(BitVector)
    new.__dict__ = {
        "size": bitvector.size, # size is an int and immutable
        "vector": bitvector.vector[:], # vector is an array, this is enough to get a deepcopy
        # the copy will be disassociated with any file it originated from
        # this emulates how BitVector.deep_copy works
        "filename": None,
        "FILEIN": None,
        "FILEOUT": None
    }
    return new
```

To copy your list you would now do:

```
new_list = [bitvector_copy(vec) for vec in old_list]
```

For most use cases that should be enough. However, this isn't an exact deep copy though. Whilst all the new `BitVector`s are independent, it causes problems if the list contains references to the same bit vector eg.

```
old_list = [BitVector(size=8)] * 2
assert old_list[0] is old_list[1]
new_list = [bitvector_copy(vec) for vec in old_list]
assert new_list[0] is new_list[1] # AssertionError!
```

With a few modifications you can modify the copy function to work with `copy.deepcopy` and have the function return a true deep copy. This does slow the copying down a little bit though.

```
def bitvector_deepcopy(self, memo):
    if id(self.vector) in memo:
        vector = memo[id(self.vector)]
    else:
        vector = memo[id(self.vector)] = self.vector[:]
    new = BitVector.__new__(BitVector)
    new.__dict__ = {
        "size": self.size,
        "vector": vector,
        "filename": None,
        "FILEIN": None,
        "FILEOUT": None
    }
    return new
BitVector.__deepcopy__ = bitvector_deepcopy
```

Comment: Instead of modifying the class I think it's better to just create a subclass `FastCopyBitVector` which reimplements that operation...

Comment: I would do this, but the problem is that the BitVector class is not well setup up for subclassing. All of it's methods would have to be reimplemented as they are hard coded to return  objects of type BitVector.

Comment: Yes, that's one issue with subclassing in general, and especially with built-ins. However Modifying a class like you are doing is *really* awful. In most cases a change done in this way can broke a lot of other code/libraries (since you are modifying the class that is shared in all the python interpreter...) so as a practice it's *really* ugly. Sure: sometimes for a simple script a hack is worth it,...